# format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘size_t’ [-Wformat]

Tags: c, strlen

I have searched about this warning and everyone had some mistake in their code, but here is something very unexpected I could not figure out . We do expect strlen(x) to be an integer but what does this warning tell me? How couldn't strlen be int?

```
In function ‘fn_product’:
line85:3:warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘size_t’ [-Wformat]
```

My code in fn_product --

```
char *fn_product (char x[],char y[]){
  if (strlen(x)==1)    // line85
    printf("\nlength of string--%d\n", strlen(x));
  /*other code*/
}
```

Shouldn't strlen(x) be int.Why does it say to be of format size_t?

Comment: The return type of `strlen` is `size_t`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Did you check the [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strlen/)?  `strlen(3)` returns `size_t`.  Use `%zu` to print it.

As mentioned in the comments below, [clang](http://clang.llvm.org) is sometimes helpful with finding better error messages.  clang's warning for exactly this case is pretty great, in fact:

```
example.c:6:14: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument
      has type 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wformat]
    printf("%u\n", strlen("abcde"));
            ~^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            %zu
1 warning generated.
```

Comment: But I have been into c programming from a year.Never encountered such a warning. Well the warning disappeared.:)

Comment: @optimist, I guess you've had warnings levels turned down or off, or you've been using sloppy compilers.  `strlen()` has returned `size_t` since *at least* C89, so that's 20+ years.  I'm sure it's been longer even, but I don't have an older spec to check.

Comment: I have been using gcc compiler. Its still the same. Can you suggest better compilers for ubuntu?

Comment: @optimist Changing the compiler is the wrong strategy. Write correct code.

Comment: I agree with @Daniel on that one. clang is pretty great when it comes to error messages, though.

Comment: @DanielFischer I too agree with you :).. Suggestions always welcomed.Thanks Carl and Daniel.

Comment: @optimist Sure, clang works on many platforms (and in no way I wanted to insinuate that clang is a worse compiler than gcc).

Comment: @CarlNorum Well one more doubt,what is %zu,it surely is not of format int. Then how are this conditions valid?       if (strlen(x)==1),or such expressions when we compare them with integers?

Comment: @optimist, as you can see in the warning message above, `size_t` is an `unsigned long` (on my machine at least).  The regular integer promotions take place when doing comparisons like the one you describe, so there should be no problems there.  `%zu` is certainly an  integer format - that's what the `u` is for.  The `z` is just a portable size modifier for `size_t`.  You could just as well use `%lu` in my example, but it's less portable (imagine a machine where `size_t` is an `unsigned int`, for example).

Comment: @optimist `z` is a gcc extension, `%lu` works without warning too (on platforms where `size_t` is a long, such as yours). (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`).

Comment: @Kevin - The `z` length modifier is part of standard C99 (7.19.6.1 paragraph 7).

Comment: @CarlNorum so it is. I was compiling without an explicit standard (i.e. c89)

Comment: @Carl Norum are you sure the part about a laxed compiler is correct. I have always used gcc *.c -Wall to compile my c programs and I have never seen that message till I moved my code to a 64 bit computer.

Comment: @cokedude, the compiler isn't required to emit helpful warnings, but it's nice when it does.  I'm not sure I follow your question.

Answer (score -1):

use "%ld" instead of "%d".

```
printf("%ld", strlen(ch));
```

Comment: `%zu` is specifically for `size_t` I like the idea of %ld, assuming you were thinking that it wasn't an integer, but `%d` is supposed to work for `size_t`, along with `%zu` -- something else is going on here.

Answer (score -2):

Add `(int)` to your code, it should fix the error:

```
printf("\nlength of string--%d\n", (int)strlen(x))
```

Comment: You have a typo. Also, I don't think it's strictly safe to cast `size_t` to `int`.

Comment: I had the same problem on a x64bit OS and it fixed the issue

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `int(strlen(x))` or `(int)strlen(x)` instead of `int()strlen(x)`?

Comment: look at the image bellow and BTW i'm not  a c programmer

Comment: This is OK only if the length of the string is `INT_MAX` or shorter; otherwise it causes undefined behaviour.  An improvement would be to use `%u` or `%lu` and cast to `unsigned` or `unsigned long` respectively (if you're worried about portability of `%zu`).

Comment: Always think three times before solving a problem with casting